# VMWare Player pauses often

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I'm using a 64bit Windows 8 inside `vmplayer`, with 2 virtual processor cores, virtual hard disk resides on a fast local disc and is not preallocated; host CPU is Intel i7 3770, should be capable of hardware virtualisation but I don't know if VMWare uses it; NAT networking; Sound card connected, USB connected, accelerated 3D graphics (NVidia 313.30 on host)

My problem is, that the VM often pauses for a few seconds, and then speeds up for a few seconds to reach real time again. Time in the VM actually moves faster after the pause, for example all animations using timers speed up.

When running, the `vmware-vmx` process shows ~150% CPU usage in `top`, but 0% when pausing (and `D` state i.e. waiting for IO). `iotop` shows normal disk writes from `vmware-vmx` threads, but during pauses, the `flush` kernel thread uses 99%.

Are there some options to try so that VMWare doesn't wait for IO? I've tried a few things available from the GUI but the issue never went away…

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was happening because a floppy drive was connected to the VM even though the host had no access to one. Once I "Disconnected" it from the VM from the "Removable Devices" dropdown, the issue went away. This was a Windows 8 host with VMWare 9 running Ubuntu. It also happened for a windows guest.

Comment: I don't have a virtual floppy, but a physical partition as another virtual disk, this sounds similar, I'll try disconnecting it… (it feels like disconnecting the sound card helps a bit, too)